# when i press back fragments change but navigation view does not select the menu item

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

```
package com.example.backstack


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView
```

**Main Activity on create function overriden**

```
lateinit var bottomNavigationView:BottomNavigationView
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener,FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
//    lateinit var  fragmentManager:FragmentManager
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadFragments(FeedFragment())
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigation)
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this)


    }
```

**Fragments are loaded**

```
fun loadFragments(fragment:Fragment?):Boolean{

        if(fragment != null){
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
             replace(R.id.parentFrame,fragment).
             addToBackStack(null)
             .commit()

        }
        return true

    }
```

**which navigation item clicked**

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        var fragment:Fragment? = null
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.feedFragment -> fragment = FeedFragment()
            R.id.videosFragment -> fragment = VideosFragment()
            R.id.exploreFragment -> fragment = ExploreFragment()
        }
        return loadFragments(fragment)
    }
```

**Backstack function is written but i don't know how to make it function provide me with some possible solutions**

```
override fun onBackStackChanged() {

            val bse = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().backStackEntryCount - 1)
            //bse will be the backstack entry for current fragment
            if (bse.name == FeedFragment::class.java.getName()) {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true)
            } else if (bse.name == VideosFragment::class.java.getName()) {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true)
            }
            else if (bse.name == ExploreFragment::class.java.getName()) {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true)
            }
        }



}
```

*when i press back fragments change but navigation view does not select the menu item*